# Wordpress W3Total Cache and redis failover

Tags: wordpress, caching, redis, high-availability, w3-total-cache

I'm trying to create a Wordpress webpage with Redis and HA, but my problem is that looks like W3 Total Cache don't works with failover redis servers...

My configuration looks like this:

```
+--------+ +--------+     +--------+
|        | |        |     |        |
| Web 1  | | Web 2  |     | Web N  |
|        | |        |     |        |
|        | |        | ... |        |
+----+---+ +---+----+     +---+----+
     |         |              |
     | +-------+   +----------+
     | |           |
  +--+-+---+       |    +--------+
  |Redis   +-------+    |Redis   |
  |Master  |            |Slave   |
  |        +------------+        |
  |Sentinel|            |Sentinel|
  +---+----+            +----+---+
      |                      |
      |      +--------+      |
      |      |        |      |
      |      |Sentinel|      |
      +------+        +------+
             |        |
             +--------+
```

The Redis sentinel seems to work fine and when master is out, the slave start to work, but the W3 Total Cache looks like is unable to manage that failover configuration and then the webpage stop working.

On the image I've linked only the master because is the actual configuration, but during the tests I've configured both servers on Total Cache plugin and the behaviour is the same:
When master fails, the page stop working. If I change the configuration file to remove the master, then is when Total Cache starts to use the slave.

How I can do to make W3TC to use the slave when the master fails?.

Thanks and greetings!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've configured the slave as writable and I've used HAProxy to use both servers. When master fails the HAProxy detects it and then use only the slave.

Comment: Some time later I found a better way, because you can use HaProxy to ask to Redis if that node is the Master node and mark it as up, then the traffic will go only to master. The way I've posted above works, but have some problems because data saved in slave is not copied to master.

Comment: What is better way to connect  redis with W3TC when we have redis and master slave setup with sentinel